# Create setup with two executables with InstallShield 2009

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, installation, installshield

I'd like to create a setup with InstallShield 2009 that this one must install the framework .NET 4.0 and after this install a application developed in c#.

I already have both setups (The Framework .NET 4.0 and my C# application).

How to create a project on InstallShield 2009 to install both setups in just one?

Thanks.

Comment: You've now asked 6 questions and not accepted any of the answers.  You might want to figure out how this site works before asking any more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tool was used to create the installer for the C# application?  If it was me, I'd use an InstallShield Basic MSI project to create the installer for the C# application and then add the .NET 4.0 (Client or Full) Setup Prerequisite to the project.

Otherwise you can upgrade to InstallShield 2012 and use the new Suite project type to encapsulate the two EXE packages that you describe.

Comment: But InstallShield 2009 doesn't have this version (4.0) of .NET to add as Setup Prerequisite. There's another way? Thanks

Comment: It would be trivial to write your own PRQ file and even easier to download the evaluation of 2012 and copy the PRQ file into your 2009 environment. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the tutorial. Perhaps you should try fishing harder and longer before giving up. If you can't figure out how to apply the lesson to .NET 4.0 then I'd suggest just downloading the eval version of 2012, install it to a machine and grab the 11 PRQ files found in the C:\Program Files\InstallShield\2012\SetupPrerequisites directory. Open up and InstallShield and they will appear in the Redist screen. Right click and download content to get the rest from Microsoft / InstallShield.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I can't install the version 2012. I have to found a way for 2009. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Why can't you install it? Throw it on a VM, grab the files and roll back the VM. Or, use the InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2010 ( it's free to VS2010 customers ). Either way, grab the PRQ files and copy them into your 2009 environment.  I can't imagine why you can't do this but if you really can't, then go back to my tutorial and study it into you figure it out.   There's no other way to do this.

Comment: Ah, just to clarify, what is that complete path in the windows registry in the step 2 of your tutorial?

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding something in your tutorial, but your sure it fits to the .net 4.0?

Comment: The answer is it depends.  Are you trying to install .NET 4.0 Client Profile or .NET 4.0 Full?  Also make sure you understand the concept of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SYSWOW64 if you are on a 64bit O/S.  The point is your looking for something that tells you whether it's installed already or not.  Checkout HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full

Comment: That's what I was talking about! Worked here! Was just missing this registry key. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey man, can you help me again? Now I'd like to make a pack of it. Because like that (prerequisites) when I build the setup, it creates a folder containing the prerequisite's setup. Now I have to make that all of it be just one executable. How can I do that? Thanks